# Bash Curl request PHP array

Tags: bash, curl, post

I need to send a request with POST containing something like this:

`values = [
    test1 => foo,
    test2 => bar,
]`

This is how my post request looks like:

```
curl_opts=(
    --silent
    --header "Content-type: application/json"
    --header "Authorization: Bearer foobar"
)

data=$(printf '{"values[test1]":"%s", "values[test2]":"%s"}' "foo" "bar")
auth_response=$(curl "${curl_opts[@]}" -v -s -H -X POST -d "$data" "http://$SITE" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout)
```

But this does not work. A POST request with Postman with the same variables does work.

Comment: What format does the site you are POSTing to expect? It seems strange that you would have to send an array in PHP syntax...

Comment: Exactly that format. Everything other than values[test1] => foo does not get accepted

Comment: in that case you need to change the code to use the right syntax because at the moment it doesn't match.